# How do I load a module/class from my config/application.rb file in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, module, load

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I’ve created a file at lib/app_config/aws_secrets.rb, which looks like

```
require 'yaml'

module mycoAppConfig
  class AwsSecrets

    def self.load
      …
    end
  end
end
```

Then in my config/application.rb file, I have invoked the above method using

```
AppConfig::AwsSecrets.load
```

But when I run a rake task, I’m getting this uninitialized constant error

```
NameError: uninitialized constant MycoWeb::Application::AppConfig
/Users/myuser/Documents/workspace/myco/myapp/config/application.rb:120:in `block in <class:Application>'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@myapp/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@myapp/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@myapp/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@myapp/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.5@myapp/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:53:in `before_configuration'
/Users/myuser/Documents/workspace/myco/myapp/config/application.rb:113:in `<class:Application>'
/Users/myuser/Documents/workspace/myco/myapp/config/application.rb:9:in `<module:mycoWeb>'
```

What’s the proper way to include/name my library?

Comment: name it `AppConfig` (not mycoAppConfig) then `require "app_config/aws_secrets"` then call `AppConfig::AwsSecrets.load`.

Comment: I'm named thigns as you suggested, but the line "require 'app_config/aws_secrets'" to the top of config/application.rb throws a "LoadError: cannot load such file -- app_config/aws_secrets" when I run any rake task (e.g "bin/rake assets:precompile")

Comment: I think lib gets added to load path after the configuration. try this `require_relative "../lib/app_config/aws_secrets"`.

Comment: That dies with an error.  I opened a separate question about it -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72222399/in-rails-4-how-do-i-include-a-module-that-defines-app-config

Answer (score 0):

according to the naming convention you should use module name as `AppConfig`

```
require 'yaml'

module AppConfig
  class AwsSecrets

    def self.load
      …
    end
  end
end
```

```
application.rb

config.eager_load_paths += %W( #{config.root}/lib/**/*.rb )
```

Comment: I gave this a go, but get a "LoadError: cannot load such file -- app_config/aws_secrets" when I include "require 'app_config/aws_secrets'" at the top of my config/application.rb file

Comment: config.eager_load_paths += %W(
  #{config.root}/lib/**/*.rb
)

try this @dave

Comment: Tried this as well but doesn't work.  I placed your line before the "config.before_configuration do" line where I call "AppConfig::AwsSecrets.load".

Comment: let's do google meet?